# Código entra em loop infinito ao utilizar numero negativo - Python

Tags: python, loop, ciclo-infinito

programa simples em que o usuário vai informar o numero máximo, mínimo e o numero escolhido.
Com esses parâmetros, a maquina vai descobrir qual o numero escolhido pelo usuário.

Porem quando o usuário escolhe um numero negativo (já informando o numero mínimo como um negativo menor ou igual ao escolhido) o programa entra em loop infinito.

Alguem sabe onde estou errando?

```
from random import randint

numeromaximo = (int(input('Qual o valor maximo? ')))
numerominimo = (int(input('Qual o valor minimo? ')))
resposta = (int(input('Qual o numero escolhido: ')))
tentativa = 0
palpite = ""

while palpite is not resposta:
tentativa += 1
palpite = randint(numerominimo, numeromaximo)
print(f'O palpite da maquina é {palpite}, seu numero escolhido é maior, menor ou acertou?')
if palpite < resposta:
    print("o valor escolhido é maior, escolhendo outro numero\n")
    numerominimo = palpite
elif palpite > resposta:
    print('O valor escolhido é menor, escolhendo novo numero!!!\n')
    numeromaximo = palpite
else:
    print(f'O numero escolhido pelo usuario é {resposta}')
    print(f'Numero descoberto apos {tentativa} tentativas')
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Em vez de `is not`, use `!=` - ou seja, `while palpite != resposta:` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085656

Answer (score 0):

Faltou a adição de entrada "resposta = (int(input('Qual o numero escolhido: ')))" para verificar a condição novamente dentro do while, assim quando a pessoa acerta o número do palpite, o laço se encerra, conforme fiz abaixo:

```
from random import randint

numeromaximo = (int(input('Qual o valor maximo? ')))
numerominimo = (int(input('Qual o valor minimo? ')))
resposta = (int(input('Qual o numero escolhido: ')))
tentativa = 0
palpite = 0

while palpite is not resposta:
    tentativa += 1
    palpite = randint(numerominimo, numeromaximo)
    print(f'O palpite da maquina é {palpite}, seu numero escolhido é maior, menor ou acertou?')
    if palpite < resposta:
        print("o valor escolhido é maior, escolhendo outro numero\n")
        numerominimo = palpite
        resposta = (int(input('Qual o numero escolhido: ')))

    elif palpite > resposta:
        print('O valor escolhido é menor, escolhendo novo numero!!!\n')
        numeromaximo = palpite
        resposta = (int(input('Qual o numero escolhido: ')))

    else:
        print(f'O numero escolhido pelo usuario é {resposta}')
        print(f'Numero descoberto apos {tentativa} tentativas')
```